# A batsman can score 0,1,2,3,4 or 6 runs from a ball. the number of different sequences...

Tags: permutations, combinations

A batsman can score 0,1,2,3,4 or 6 runs from a ball. the number of different sequences in which he can score exactly 30 runs in an over of six balls is:

Comment: What have you tried? Have you, for instance, tried just listing all the possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possibilities are ,
1)  5 sixes and a zero.
2)  4 sixes and a four and a two.
3)  3 sixes and 3 fours.
4) 4sixes and a 2 three.

So possible ways are,
$$\frac{6!}{5!} + \frac{6!}{4!} + \frac{6!}{3!×3!} +\frac{6!}{4!×2!}$$
$$=71$$

Answer (score 0):

You can see that 3 6's are much needed to get a sum of 30 in 6 balls

So we are left with 3 balls and 12 runs

This can be done by following ways

$6,6,0$ or $6,4,2$ or $4,4,4$ or $6,3,3$

So total possibility of the over is

$$6,6,6,6,6,0$$$$6,6,6,6,4,2$$$$6,6,6,4,4,4$$$$6,6,6,6,3,3$$

And now you have to finf unique sequences which is equivalent to say you have to permutate these overs

For 1st permutation is given by $\frac{6!}{5!}=6$

For 2nd permutation is given by $\frac{6!}{4!}=30$

For 3rd permutation is given by $\frac{6!}{3!3!}=20$

For 4th permutation is given by $\frac{6!}{4!2!}=15$

Total sequences$=6+30+20+15=71$

So $71$ should be the desired answer